# Infinite dimensional quotients of L_1 by isomorphic subspaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $M$ be a subspace of $L_1(0,1)$. If the subspace $M$ is  isomorphic to $L_1(0,1)$ and complemented, then the quotient $L_1(0,1)/M$ is clearly non-reflexive if it is infinite dimensional. So as we know, there are subspaces isomorphic to $L_1(0,1)$ but not complemented. But what can we say about the reflexivity of this quotient? If the quotient is never reflexive, this would imply that if any operator $T:L_1(0,1)\rightarrow L_1(0,1)$ is an element of the boundary of the upper-semi Fredholm operators, then the residuum operator $T^{co}: L_1^{**}/L_1 \rightarrow L_1^{**}/L_1$ definied by $T^{co}(x^{**}+L_1)=T^{**}x^{**}+L_1$ is not invertible. The latter operator plays an important role in the theory of tauberian operators.

Comment: Amir, this is the second question in a row where you ask things without giving an indication of what steps you yourself have tried in order to attack this problem. You also have not given any motivation for this series of questions.

Comment: Also, the title of the question is misleading. It is trivial that there exist non-reflexive quotients of $L^1$, but you are asking for something much more specific

Comment: My intention is the following Yemon: If the subspace $M$ isomorphic to $L_1(0,1)$ is complemented, then the quotient is clearly non-reflexive. So as we know, there are subspaces isomorphic to $L_1(0,1)$ but not complemented. But what can we say about the reflexivity of this quotient. I asked these questions for research about some questions with regard to tauberian operators.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail. You should edit this into your original question (and avoid creating two separate accounts)

Comment: My Indikation is the Folklore

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Almost anyone in research faced with a problem, whatever the level, will have tried to reduce it to a simpler problem, or to prove a weaker case, perhaps consulting other literature. At present all we have here is an interesting question, but if you showed more of your own thoughts then perhaps people here would find it easier to offer helpful suggestions

Comment: Please register one of your accounts and ask to merge your two accounts at [mathoverflow.net/contact](http://mathoverflow.net/contact).

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais I've found two more unregistered accounts of Amir: 
http://mathoverflow.net/users/38789/amir-bahman-nasseri and 
http://mathoverflow.net/users/38843/amir-bahman-nasseri

Comment: @AmirBahmanNasseri: AFAIK, everything known about $L_1/L_1$ is contained in my paper "Extensions of $c_0$" and the paper of Kalton and Pelczynski on which it is based, which gives only that $L_1/L_1$ must have finite cotype and hence cannot be superreflexive.